# Adding ActiveModel Errors to ruby class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activemodel

I'm trying to get Active Model Errors working in a standard ruby class that I'm using for stripe.

```
class Payment
  attr_reader :user, :token, :errors
  attr_accessor :base
  extend ActiveModel::Naming

  def initialize(args)
    @user    = args[:user]
    @token   = args[:stripe_token]
    @errors  = ActiveModel::Errors.new(self)
  end

  def checking_account
    begin
      account = Stripe::Account.retrieve(user.stripe_account_id)
      account.external_account = token
      account.save
    rescue Stripe::StripeError => e
      errors.add(:base, e.message)
    end
  end

  # The following methods are needed to be minimally implemented

  def read_attribute_for_validation(attr)
    send(attr)
  end

  def Payment.human_attribute_name(attr, options = {})
    attr
  end

  def Payment.lookup_ancestors
    [self]
  end
end
```

now I'm making `checking_account` fail on purpose by not supplying a token, and I'm just returned an array currently saying:

```
 => ["Invalid external_account object: must be a dictionary or a non-empty string. See API docs at https://stripe.com/docs'"]
```

now I've followed the steps on http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Errors.html so I'm not sure why this isn't working, does anybody have any idea how to fix this?

when I'm calling:

`Payment.new(user: User.find(1)).managed_account` it triggers the array above, and if I try to call `.errors` on that I get

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `errors' for #<Array:0x007f80989d8328>
```

which is obviously because it's an array and the format isn't correct.

Comment: define 'not working'.

Comment: `payment = Payment.new(user: User.find(1))` and then `payment.errors` did you try this way ?

Comment: yes that's what I did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you have should work to fill `errors`.  The issue is that you can't call `.errors` on `checking_account` because the return value from `checking_account` is an Array, not a Payment instance.  You should be able to make these calls separately on the console to review:

```
payment = Payment.new(user: User.find(1))  # Returns Payment instance
payment.checking_account
payment.errors  # Calls `errors` on Payment instance
```